# Ubuntu 22.04 shows text boot messages then the desktop won't load after restarting gdm3 once

Tags: boot, drivers, 22.04, desktop-environments

I am running Ubuntu on an opd iMac 2011. It's been working great, but after restarting gdm3 once it will not show the desktop again. I have done several reboots and reinstalling gdm3 did not fix it. I know the computer itself is fine as ssh terminal works and using an Ubuntu thumb drive I can use the *Try Ubuntu* option without any issues. Do you have any ideas about what I can do to fix this?

Screen showing black and white checkered:

[image: a screen showing black and white checkered]

I don't get the option to reinstall Ubuntu when using boot thumb drive, so I can't have the system reinstall itself without losing data. Even restarting gdm3 now shows the Ubuntu 22.04 logo with four loading dots then just goes to this screen.